# fstrim does not work (Ubuntu 14.04, ext4, Intel SSD 520)

Tags: ssd, intel, ext4, trim

I've been googling around for hours without having found an answer.

I've found some hints, but they don't correlate with each other.

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep TRIM
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 1 block)
       *    Deterministic read data after TRIM
```

which says that the TRIM function should work. (same output for /dev/sda1 if it matters)

[Gparted screenshot](http://pbrd.co/12VG07d)

which says that the partition is ext4 and is mounted on / . But if I try to fstrim manually (obvious test method), I get a failure.

```
$ sudo fstrim /
fstrim: /: FITRIM ioctl failed: Operation not supported
```

The only post I've found so far with almost the same problem had a solution that the SSD disk didn't support the TRIM function. Since I've a brand new Intel SSD 520 and `fstrim` is supported on Intel and Samsung SSDs by default (read from `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` which was in default Ubuntu installation), I'm affraid that this is not the same case.

Why is the `fstrim` not working?

Can the SAS-controller make any difference in this case?

Thank You in advance.

JM

Answer (score 0):

The controller certainly makes a difference:  Putting a trimable SSD into an external USB3 enclosure will result in the same error you are getting.